Windows API SetThreadContext does not set EFlags Carry Flag
Im trying to run machine code on windows for testing purposes,
i got a working prototype the only thing not working are EFlags
SetThreadContext seems to NOT apply EFlags to the thread correctly,
If i modify the EFlags in the CONTEXT Structure to include the carry flag cntx->EFlags |= 1; and apply it with SetThreadContext and set a breakpoint at the adress of the threads execution with gdb and dump the eflags using info registers eflags it does NOT include CF (Carry Flag)
My current Prototype:
typedef struct machine_code_t {
    char *machine_code;
    size_t machine_code_size;
} machine_code;

char code_adc[] = "\x49\x83\xD7\x00\xEB\xFA";

#define IM_CODE code_adc
int main(void) {
    CONTEXT *final_context = nullptr;
    HANDLE threadhndle = nullptr;
    CONTEXT *context = nullptr;
    machine_code machineCode = {.machine_code = IM_CODE, .machine_code_size = sizeof(IM_CODE)};
    
    auto func = reinterpret_cast<LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE>(VirtualAlloc(nullptr, machineCode.machine_code_size,
                                                                      MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE,
                                                                      PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE));
    if (func == nullptr) {
        printf("VirtualAlloc failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (std::memcpy(reinterpret_cast<void *>(func), machineCode.machine_code, machineCode.machine_code_size) ==
        nullptr) {
        printf("memcpy failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    threadhndle = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, func, nullptr, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &g_targetThreadId);
    if (threadhndle == nullptr) {
        printf("CreateThread failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    context = (CONTEXT *) calloc(1, sizeof(CONTEXT));
    if (context == nullptr) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    context->ContextFlags = CONTEXT_ALL;
    if (GetThreadContext(threadhndle, context) == 0) {
        printf("GetThreadContext failed\n");
        goto clean;
    }
    context->EFlags |= 1; // Set the carry flag
    context->R14 = 100;
    context->ContextFlags = CONTEXT_ALL;
    if (SetThreadContext(threadhndle, context) == 0) {
        printf("SetThreadContext failed\n");
        goto clean;
    }
    if (ResumeThread(threadhndle) == -1) {
        printf("ResumeThread failed\n");
        goto clean;
    }
    Sleep(100);
    if (SuspendThread(threadhndle) == -1) {
        printf("SuspendThread failed\n");
        goto clean;
    }
    final_context = (CONTEXT *) calloc(1, sizeof(CONTEXT));
    if (final_context == nullptr) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        goto clean;
    }
    final_context->ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
    if (GetThreadContext(threadhndle, final_context) == 0) {
        printf("GetThreadContext failed\n");
        goto clean;
    }
    
    printf("Initial R15: %lld\n", context->R15);
    printf("Final R15: %lld\n", final_context->R15);
    
    clean:
    free(context);
    if (final_context != nullptr) free(final_context);
    if (threadhndle != nullptr) CloseHandle(threadhndle);
    if (func != nullptr) VirtualFree(reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(func), 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    return 0;
}

What i also have tryed is setting bit 1 additionaly (eflag |= 2) because i have read its reserved but no change
Im running
"\x49\x83\xD7\x00\xEB\xFA"

==
start:
adc R15, 0
jmp start

Expectet output that R15 is 1 (Carry Flag added then cleared, R15 will not change because its adding 0)
Actual Output: R15 is 0
Debugging:
put gdb breakpoint at adress of func
dump EFlags, see CF (Carry Flag is not set)
(gdb) break *0x00..... //adress stored in func variable
// Wait for hit on breakpoint should show [New Thread ...] then hit the brakpoint
(gdb) x/i $pc // should show adc $0x0,%r15 (reversed in comparison to intel syntax but still correct)
(gdb) info registers eflags // should show something like [ PF ZF IF ]

As seen the c++ definetly set the carry flag corectly, but its not set in the actual thread
Thats my question WHY does SetThreadContext not set the carry flag corectly in the thread
Aditional Resources i have used:
x86 Flags
GetThreadContext
CreateThread
ResumeThread
SuspendThread
CloseHandle

Note that the documentation says that "Some values in the CONTEXT structure that cannot be specified are silently set to the correct value. This includes bits in the CPU status register that specify the privileged processor mode, global enabling bits in the debugging register, and other states that must be controlled by the operating system." It's unclear why that would include the carry flag though.

Since you create the thread in a suspended state, I wonder if some library code runs in the context of the new thread before execution reaches your func.  If so, it would probably involve instructions that set FLAGS.  Does your context->R14 = 100; get applied to the thread?  If so, that might just be a sign that the library code doesn't use R14.  Does setting RSP to something invalid make it fault?  If so, that's another sign that other instructions are running in the new thread context before yours, because you don't do any stack ops.

You could let the thread start and then suspend it, for example by adding an instruction that sets a variable you can wait for in the main thread.

If you create the thread in a non-suspended state and sleep for a few milliseconds to give it time to enter your loop; that would sidestep that problem.  Then you could suspending it, get/set its context (like R15=42; EFLAGS |= 1;) and either check in GDB for the current EFLAGS, or resume it and check later for R15=43.

(If that works, then this question is really: "Do EFLAGS and register context survive unchanged to the start of the function given for a thread created with CREATE_SUSPENDED?" and the answer is no.  If that's what's going on.)

@PeterCordes Yes R14 and all other registers get applyed even RIP can be manipulated

GDB should let you debug the new thread if you never wake it up, or only after a spin-wait on a variable you set with GDB.  That would be a way to double-check what instructions run in the context of that thread.  And you can look at its RIP and disassemble from there.

@Jester Yes i have read that as far as i understand this refers to the Reserved Bits & as stated Privelege, Global and debug bits
Logicaly it makes no sense CF is requred to be managed by the OS and in gdb you can manualy overwritte the entire eflags register even reserved bits so idk but good point thx

@PeterCordes Ok i never tought about it from that perspective thx, will try that as soon as im back on pc.

At least on wine, printing the initial RIP indeed does not show it pointing to the func. Forcing it to point there makes the carry flag setting take effect.

MS's docs only say privileged and reserved EFLAGS bits get silently ignored.  If (unlikely) it also ignores writes to other bits, that would be a bug in the docs.  Good point about setting EFLAGS from within GDB; it probably uses the same API to manipulate its target process.  (If you actually single-step or continue to another breakpoint, you should find that reserved and privileged bits revert to their old values.  The ignoring might happen when the OS context-switches to the task, not when you call SetThreadContext. Or GDB doesn't re-check with the OS after set $eflags=...; same on Linux)

Thx guys worked like a charm :)

if you look for RIP from CONTREXT you can view that it point to ntdll.RtlUserThreadStart but not on your func. and RCX register is point to your func. so you set EFlags at ntdll.RtlUserThreadStart. before it call your func the EFlags of course will change to undefined state. so this and must not work.
however you not need pass EFlags as parameter to shellcode. you can direct call it. of if you want execute it and another thread, you can pass up to 3 parameters ( rcx, rdx, r8 in case x64) if execute it in apc callback or single parameter in rcx

Thx, works no problem decided to just force point RIP at my func

@FireDragon91245 in this case your function must direct call ExitThread (RtlExitUserThread). in any case i not view sense try pass EFlags to function as start parameter

yes i already call ExitThread thx for the hint anyways. For further context i need this for testing, im making executing tests for my x86 assembler using this. i aditionaly use Vectored Exception Handlers and events to monitore the execution and ensure the thread is like a sandbox where if anything fails it can be handled gracefully. for example testing ADC needs CF set for testing

@FireDragon91245 - for this yu not need create new thread. you can execute code direct
